# Каким образов создать сокет, но при условии что он уже не включен?

Tags: java

Или же как вынести сокет из блока if else?

```
package com.lordradix.client;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class SenderThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String line = null;
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        strBuilder.append(params[i]);
    }
    String command = strBuilder.toString();

    try{
        Socket socket = new Socket("ip", 6666);
        InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

        if(socket.isConnected()) {
            out.writeUTF(command);
            out.flush();
            line = in.readUTF();
            return line.toString();
        }else{
            throw new Exception("Socket not alive!");
        }
}catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.toString();

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: выложите свой код и напишите, что не работает.

Comment: Всё работает, но при активации метода в котором сокет - сокет создаётся ещё раз(я ведь правильно понимаю?) и сервер на котором ограничение в 2 подкл. сокета уже не может работать дальше.

Comment: я не знаю что у вас там создается, свой код вы не показываете, а гадалок тут нет.

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вынесите в поля класса

```
class SenderThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String> {
    private Socket socket;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        ...

        try{
            if(socet == null){
                socket = new Socket("ip", 6666);
            }
            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
            ...
        }catch(Exception ex){
            return ex.toString();
        }
    }
}
```